# NCrunch errors after update to latest version 3.20

Tags: ncrunch

NCrunch (which is wonderful) has starting throwing errors since I updated it to the latest version this morning.

So everything was working perfectly prior to the upgrade (which it prompted me to do).

Since updating and restarting the machine I am now getting the following and similar messages :-

System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\NCrunch\24252\11_ncrunchreferences\System.Net.Http.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at UnitTests.xxx.nnn.com.Controllers.Application.GetTests.WhenTheManagerCallFails()

However, my NUnit tests still pass, so its just affecting NCrunch? any ideas I have looked in the forum, and on SO and not found any clues... anybody have any advice?

Comment: I have already tried the Pre-load all assembly references into test environment to true to see if this fixes the issue, but to no avail.

Comment: I have checked the folder in question and I can See System.Net.Http.Dll, so I am therefore assuming its some sort of dependency, but what that might be that NCrunch is now demanding be present I do not know..